# Google drive V3 api files: watch

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-workspace

I am using the v3 drive files: watch api: [files.watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch)

When I use a spreadsheet from my drive, I am receiving notifications. However it doesn't work when a spreadsheet from team drive is used. I have tried using the supportsTeamDrives: true as mentioned in the API but still unsuccessful.

Is there any additional param to be requested or does google drive api not support watch for team drive?

Any solution will be helpful.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Endpoint used: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[SPREADSHEETID]/watch

URL params: supportsTeamDrives: true, includeTeamDriveItems: true, teamDriveId: DRIVE_ID

Payload: id: 
UUID,
type: 'web_hook',
address: NOTIFICATION_URL,
expiration:1543407976000

The webhook gets created. But doesn't notify when the file in drive is updated. It works for files in My drive as mentioed in description above.